# Undo saving to Drive

Tags: gmail, google-drive

In the new gmail interface that was introduced last year, I often misclick on the Google Drive icon, which results in the attachment being saved in my Google Drive. How to undo it?

[image]

Comment: The only way I've found is to navigate to Drive and delete it! The "Save to Drive" button does change to a "Show in Drive" button after it is saved, so the jump to Drive is relatively painless.